# Resize evenly GroupBoxs when resizing form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, resize, groupbox

I have a `form` (600x500 px). In this `form` there are 2 `groupboxes`. The first one being 260 px and the second one 330 px.

What I would like is that when I resize the `form`, those two boxes resize with it, but by keeping the proportions. (the second one bigger then the first).

No matter how I set the `Anchor` points, I dont seem to be able to do this.

Comment: Anchors don't solve this.  A TableLayoutPanel does.

Comment: yay! thank you! post it as answer so i can accept it!

Comment: @HansPassant +1 I was writing my answer when you add this comment.

Comment: sorry Chris, hans was first. if he posts the answer within a few minutes then i accept his, else i accept yours. but maybe you can answer my other question! :)

Comment: No problem :) I didn't see its comment when I started to test and write my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with a `TableLayoutPanel` like this:

- Add a `TableLayoutPanel` on your `Form`. Set the anchor to `Left`, `Top`, `right` (and `Bottom` in needed) or set Dock property to `Fill`
- Add two columns on this `TableLayoutPanel` (by default there is two columns and two rows, so remove the last row)
- Insert your `GroupBoxs` to each cell
- set the Dock property to `Fill` or `Top` for each `GroupBox`
- By default the Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles is `System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent`, so just adjust the first column with in designer as you need.

Result:

Before resizing
[image]

After resizing (image is reduced so you can see that it keeps proportion)

[image]